# How to save data from pandastable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating a table interface in which the user will receive a table from pandastable and write some data. Then, I need to save the updated pandastable to make some evaluations. How could I do this?

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
import pandas as pd

class TestApp(Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    self.parent = parent
    Frame.__init__(self)
    self.main = self.master
    self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
    self.main.title('Table app')
    f = Frame(self.main)
    f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
    df = pd.read_excel('2018.xlsx','November',7)
    x = 'desc'
    nome = df[x].values.tolist()
    name = []
    for i in range(len(nome)):
        if nome[i] == nome[i] and nome[i] != x:
            name.append(nome[i])

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({x:name})
    cfop = [float('Nan') for i in range(len(name))]
    cst_in = [float('Nan') for i in range(len(name))]
    cst_out = [float('Nan') for i in range(len(name))]
    ncm = [float('Nan') for i in range(len(name))]
    icms = [float('Nan') for i in range(len(name))]
    df1['ncm'] = pd.Series(ncm)
    df1['CST in'] = pd.Series(cst_in)
    df1['CST out'] = pd.Series(cst_out)
    df1['CFOP'] = pd.Series(cfop)
    df1['ICMS'] = pd.Series(icms)
    self.table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df1, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
    pt.show()
    return 
app = TestApp()
app.mainloop()

df1 = Table.model.df1
```

The user is expected to fill the columns `ncm`, `CFOP`, `ICMS`, `CST in` and `CST out`. Right now, he can write on those columns, but the data is lost once he closes the app. I want to get the data that he writes and put in a variable DataFrame.

Comment: As I had discovered, in my case, simply declaring the variable df1 as global solves the problem: even when the pandastable window is closed by the user, the data inserted by him is stored in the global variable, which allows me to make the calculations I need.

Comment: If that's the case, why not use `df1` as an instance attribute `self.df1` instead? Declaring global defeats the purpose of your OOP approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following line:

```
pt.doExport(filename="test2.csv")
```

This will result in a .csv file with all of the data from the table.